# Change behaviour of F1-12 keys

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I just installed Ubuntu on my new Dell Chromebook 13. I know that many of you don't have experience with it but my question is very generic, so please help me out anyway.

The keyboard doesn't have an fn key but the buttons on top do behave like F-keys in Ubuntu. Their normal behavior is the inverted way. Now one would say that it's unsupported to swap the behavior in my case but the strange thing is: in an Xfce session they do behave like they should (so not as F keys meaning the behavior is swapped there)! So it should be possible somehow to do this in a Unity session as well, right?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you please run `xev` in a terminal? It reports all captured input events. Now could you focus the opening window, press and release the Fn key, and include the reports about those two events in your question? If the Fn key doesn't generate X events, that would also be a useful information.

Comment: The only output I get is:

^[[17~^[[18~^[[17~^[[18~^C

So xev doesn't seem to respond to them. But I really don't get why as, like I said, they work fine inverted in Xfce. So it should be a software thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by reassigning you shortcut keys like this:

1. Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select System Settings.
2. Open Keyboard and select the Shortcuts tab.
3. Select a category in the left pane, and the row for the desired action on the right. The current shortcut definition will change to New accelerator…
4. Hold down the desired key combination, or press Backspace to clear.

A full explanation can be found at this link. [Set Keyboard Shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the brightness or refresh shortcuts there. I could add them on my own but I don't know what commands I need to use.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you with that later.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I still find it weird that when I log into the Xfce session the buttons work like they should (meaning the inverted way that I want in Unity as well). So it's no hardware thing, it's a software thing.

Comment: So I got a little further. The reason it works in Xfce is because the keyboard model is set to chromebook_m I tried to change the model to chromebook_m using

setxkbmap -model chromebook_m -layout us -variant altgr-intl

That works fine, except that my dead keys are gone now despite having the variant set to altgr-intl as you can see. How can I get my dead keys back using that command?